# How to draw a 4 pointed star using glut openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, opengl-compat

I want to draw a 4pointed star using GLUT and openGL in C++. Here is my code

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glVertex3f(0.0f,6.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f,4.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(3.0f,3.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f,2.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,2.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-3.0f,3.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,4.0f,0.0f);

glEnd();
```

The problem is the shape directly goes to 3,3 from 0,6

can anyone help me how to fix this,
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9418M.png)

I want something like this
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UJfN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st point of the the `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` primitiv is always held fixed (See [Triangle primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives)). Just start the `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` primitiv at one of the "inner" points:

```cpp
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    
    glVertex3f(1.0f,4.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(3.0f,3.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f,2.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,2.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-3.0f,3.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,4.0f,0.0f);

    glVertex3f(0.0f,6.0f,0.0f);

glEnd();
```

[image]

Comment: I was using GL_POLYGON but someone suggested to use trianglefan . it also didn't work using polygons. are they both same?

Comment: @sfbshoccho In your question you use `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`. `GL_POLYGON` is deprecated. Anyway, in the compatibility specification is specified for `POLYGON` that *"The bounding line segments are specified in the same way as
line loops."*. Hence it should behave the same.

Comment: Yes In my question I was using triangle fan. but I was just asking . Our teacher taught us GL_Polygons today but didn't mention anything like this. I searched online and found that GL_Polygons is depreciated and I should use trianglfan . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a triangle fan but setting its central vertex (the initial one) at 0,6,0.

You probably want to change your geometry so that your central vertex is at the origin (for symmetry). It also works to move the first vertex down to the bottom as @Rabbid76 shows.